XGBoost WARNING No visible GPU is found, setting device to CPU
System Information

XGBoost Version: 2.1.3
NVIDIA Driver Version: 565.57.01
CUDA Version: 12.6 (from nvcc) and 12.7 (from nvidia-smi)
GPU: Tesla T4
Operating System: Ubuntu 24.04
Python Version: 3.11.10
torch.cuda.is_available(): True

Despite the system indicating that CUDA and the GPU are available, I am encountering the following warning from XGBoost:

XGBoost WARNING: /workspace/src/context.cc:43: No visible GPU is found, setting device to CPU.

How to resolve this issue?
